# How to troubleshoot slow SASS compile times?

Tags: compilation, sass, compass

Pardon the open-ended question, but I don't know how to get more specific at this point.

I've inherited a project, and compass is taking 15 seconds to compile sass in this one particular project. I have two other projects on the same computer where sass takes 1 - 1.5 seconds to compile.

What could cause sass to compile so much slower in one project compared to two others on the same computer?

I made a copy of the troublesome project and stripped it way, way down, so it's now actually much simpler than my other two projects.  In so doing, I got the compile down from 15 seconds to about 2 seconds, but I should be seeing a much faster compile than 2 seconds given how tiny the project now is.  The entire project now has only one scss file, and has only one @import statement...

```
@import "compass";
```

How is this project taking ~2 seconds to compile when my other much more complex projects take 1 second?  There is only one file in the sass directory at this point: main.scss.

Comment: I don't know if I should take down the question, or answer it, but I ended up switching to libsass last night and compile times are now down to 1 second.  I'm now using libsass + grunt + node.  With NPM, I installed grunt-sass.  With bower, I installed compass-mixins and susy.

Comment: Stackoverflow supports answering your own questions - besides it means you found something out yourself which is always nice ;). SO has the option to "answer your own question Q&A style" when you create a question and already know the answer. For questions which answers you find later you can fill in your own answer on the thread but you'll have to wait 2 days to be able to mark it.

Comment: Comment was getting long - anyways the most important thing is that if it's not duplicate and contains useful information it's just additional knowledge you're sharing  ;)